# Rails routing error: receiving Unknown Action exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes.rb file, I have the following:

```
controller :sessions do
  get 'login' => :new
  post 'login' => :create
  delete 'logout' => :destory
end
```

And in a view file, I have this link:

```
<%= link_to 'Logout', logout_url, :method => :delete%>
```

But when click the Logout link, I get this error

```
Unknown action

The action 'destory' could not be found for SessionsController
```

Comment: Potentially a spelling mistake: destroy instead of destory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route is fine, the problem is that your `SessionsController` has no `destroy` action defined

Actually, I just noticed, your route has `destory` instead of `destroy`